# Ошибка при создании регистрации для laravel проекта c blade

Tags: php, laravel

При добавлении blade в свой laravel проект и доходя до команды npm run dev blade просто собирается, но не запускается. Как это исправить?
Laravel v9.52.9
PHP v8.2.7

```
Вывод консоли при выполнении команды npm run dev:



Laravel Mix v6.0.49


✔ Compiled Successfully in 1667ms
┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┬──────────┐
│                                                                                                      File │ Size     │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼──────────┤
│                                                                                                /js/app.js │ 701 KiB  │
│                                                                                               css/app.css │ 34.5 KiB │
└───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┴──────────┘
webpack compiled successfully
```

Comment: Blade в Laravel еть по умолчанию, что значит: "При добавлении blade в свой laravel проект"? "Blade просто собирается, но не запускается" -- это как? Blade -- это шаблонизатор написаный на PHP, какое отношение это имеет вообще к NPM?

Comment: Для создания регистрации по этому гайду https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-blade

Comment: При выполнении команды php artisan breeze:install blade выбрал Vue.js

Comment: И? Вы установили Laravel Breeze с "Blade stack", как и описано [здесь](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-blade), наверное, потому что я там не вижу команды `php artisan breeze:install blade`. Я так и не понял, Вы чего ожидаете? Какого еще запуска? Или запуска чего? "Выбрал Vue.js", для Vue там другая [команда](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/starter-kits#breeze-and-inertia) -- `php artisan breeze:install vue`, Вы уж определитесь.

Comment: При выполнении команды php artisan breeze:install предлогается выбор из Vue,js, React, Blade и API

Comment: Мне игтересно как после сборки запустить laravel проект с регистрацией

Comment: Так Вы сначала говорите что blade, потом говорите что vue. Запустить через `php artisan serve`, точно так же как и без регистрации.

Comment: Никаких новых кнопок не появилось

Comment: А Вы в документации видели что-то про какие-то новые кнопки? `Next, you may navigate to your application's /login or /register URLs in your web browser. All of Breeze's routes are defined within the routes/auth.php file.`

Comment: Видел, 404 Not Found при перероде по /login или /register

Comment: Эти роуты в `routes/auth.php` есть?

Comment: Теперь возникает исключение Vite manifest not found at: D:\Development\Web-Development\Laravel\auth\qwe\public\build/manifest.json при переходе по /login или /register

Comment: Это уже другой вопрос. Погуглил за Вас: [Vite manifest not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73045616/vite-manifest-not-found), [How to Solve Vite manifest not found at Error In Laravel 9](https://larainfo.com/blogs/how-to-solve-vite-manifest-not-found-at-error-in-laravel-9), [Laravel-9: Vite manifest not found at](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-9-vite-manifest-not-found-at-publicbuildmanifestjson?page=1&replyId=869357).

Comment: Спасибо! Заработало.